# Вычислить бесконечную сумму с заданной точностью

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Всем привет, при решении задачи возникли трудности: при вводе значения "ε" программа ничего не делает. Не могу понять где допущена ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста ее исправить. И правильно ли я ее решаю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача стоит таким образом: Вычиcлить беcкoнечную cумму c заданнoй тoчнoстью ε(ε > 0). Cчитать что требуeмая тoчнoсть дocтигнутa,если очередное слагаемое оказалось по модулю меньше ε.

Непосредственно мое "решение"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "cmath"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double i, z;
    float s, e, t;
    cout << "e>0 e=";
    cin >> e;

    s = 0; i = 0; z = -1;
    do 
    { 
            i++;
            z *= -1;
            t = z / (i*(i + 1)*(i + 2));
            s += t; 
    } 
    while (abs(t)<e);
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь что программа ничего не делает? пробовал пользоваться отладчиком?

Comment: `Cчитать что требуeмая тoчнoсть дocтигнутa,если очередное слагаемое оказалось по модулю меньше ε.` Угу так и сумму `1/n` можно вычислить...

Comment: @pavel Обратите внимание, что ряд **знакочередующийся**, так что такая оценка верная.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас цикл завершается, когда член БОЛЬШЕ точности...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double s = 1.0/6.0, e, t = 1.0/6.0;
    cout << "e>0 e= ";
    cin >> e;

    for(int i = 1; fabs(t) > e; ++i)
    {
        t *= -i/(i+3.0);
        s += t;
    }
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

На всякий случай - точная сумма ряда - `-1.25+2*ln(2)`

Comment: Зачем сишный `fabs`, если есть `std::abs`?

Comment: @alexolut Привычка...

Answer (score 1):

[Проверенное решение](http://ideone.com/MsWBO2). Упражнялся в обед.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>

    int main()
    {
        double accuracyLimit = 0;
        std::cout << "Enter range accuracy limit: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> accuracyLimit;
        std::cout << "Accuracy limit = " << accuracyLimit << std::endl;

        double sum = 0;
        double item = 0;
        double i = 1;

        do
        {
            auto numerator = std::pow(-1, i);
            auto denominator = i  * (i  + 1) * (i + 2);
            item =  numerator / denominator;
            std::cout 
                << "i=" << i 
                << " item=" <<  item << " (" << numerator << "/" << denominator << ")" 
                << std::endl;
            sum += item;
            ++i;
        }
        while (std::abs(item) > accuracyLimit);

        std::cout << std::endl << " === Calculating finished " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Range items count = " << --i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Range amount = " << sum << std::endl;
    }
```

Вывод:

```
    Enter range accuracy limit: 
    Accuracy limit = 0.001
    i=1 item=-0.166667 (-1/6)
    i=2 item=0.0416667 (1/24)
    i=3 item=-0.0166667 (-1/60)
    i=4 item=0.00833333 (1/120)
    i=5 item=-0.0047619 (-1/210)
    i=6 item=0.00297619 (1/336)
    i=7 item=-0.00198413 (-1/504)
    i=8 item=0.00138889 (1/720)
    i=9 item=-0.0010101 (-1/990)
    i=10 item=0.000757576 (1/1320)

    === Calculating finished 
    Range items count = 10
    Range amount = -0.135967
```

Comment: Старожилы, подскажите, пожалуйста. Как вывод оформить без подсветки?

Comment: убрать пробелы спереди, и выбрать другой стиль оформления в иконках. Или ` отметить или ещё как.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovskiy Да, но... 3 сложения, 2 умножения, 1 деление, не считая возведения в степень (!), там, где достаточно 1 сложения, 1 умножения, 1 деления и смены знака. И, кстати, сумма на самом деле положительная, вы со знаком ошиблись - `pow(-1,i+1)` нужен...

Comment: @harry, да, со знаком ошибся. 
Про производителдьность: Да, при вычислении рядов она бесспорно важна как нигде. Но задача, то учебная, как я понял. В реальном приложении, при профилировани, конечно же пришлось бы прийти к вашему варианту. Но и то, только в том случае, если бы этот код оказался bottleneck. В противном случае, пусть лучше код лучше читается, и выполняется дольше. Например, если этот ряд ситается только 1 раз, при старте приложения, то зачем его профилировать. Имхо, конечно.