# Зачем при присвоении добавляют .0?

Tags: c++, ряды

Всем доброго времени суток, я недавно начал изучать С++, буквально пару недель, и понял что лучшее изучение это изучения кода, попытки понять уже готовый код, и прошу помощи разобраться в коде, программа взята с соседнего вопроса, ну так как я комментировать не могу поэтому пришлось создать отдельный вопрос.

Суть программы заключается в том чтобы решить данный ряд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В коде программы встречается такой момент:

```
double s = 1.0 / 6.0, e, t = 1.0 / 6.0;
```

Интересует для чего используется вот эта приставка `.0`, 
И если не трудно, могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, объяснить программу построчно, чтобы вникнуть как она работает. Заранее благодарен.

Вот сам код программы

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double s = 1.0 / 6.0, e, t = 1.0 / 6.0;
    cout << "e>0 e= ";
    cin >> e;

    for (int i = 1; fabs(t) > e; ++i){
        t *= -i / (i + 3.0);
        s += t;
    }
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не ясно что в цикле происходит - тоесть например вы уверены что вот это - `t *= -i / (i + 3.0); ` правильно ?

Comment: @ampawd честно говоря не уверен, вот пытаюсь с помощью разобрать программу чтобы понять что к чему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну обратились бы сразу ко мне, что это я, мол, такого нарешал вам :)

Сначала теория.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения],

так что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Переходим к практике. Она изложена комментариями...

```
int main(){

    // s - Сумма ряда, t - текущий член. Я начинаю работу со второго члена, 
    // к этому моменту и сумма, и первый член равны по 1/6. Так как это double,
    // я пишу явно .0, так как запись 1/6 даст просто 0.
    double s = 1.0 / 6.0, e, t = 1.0 / 6.0;
    cout << "e>0 e= ";
    cin >> e;

    //  Цикл идет со ВТОРОГО члена.
    // Пока текущий член по модулю превышает требуемую точность
    // (критерий точности знакопеременного ряда), цикл набирает новые
    // и новые члены
    for (int i = 1; fabs(t) > e; ++i){
        // вычисляем a_{i+1} - по приведенной выше формуле,
        // зная a_i. Обратите внимание - 3.0, не просто 3!!!!!
        t *= -i / (i + 3.0);
        // Накапливаем сумму
        s += t;
    }

    // Выводим посчитанную сумму...
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Кстати, когда я вам писал это решение, вы почему-то были J.DR :) Или вас заинтересовал ответ на чужой вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо большое, я хотел под Вашим сообщением у Вас узнать, ну репутации не хватает. Нее, меня ничего не объединяет с данным ником/человеком. Просто в институте, на программирование, была точна такая же задача, ну мы ее пропустили, нам ответили: "Вы еще маленькие для такого" :) А тут вижу вопрос с задачей идентичной той которая была в методичке, и конечно стало интересно. Еще раз огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь `i` в цикле не совпадает с `i` в формуле
Для формуле при `i=1` слагаемое равно `1/6`, отсюда значения для `s` и `t`
В цикле слагаемое вычисляется не прямо по формуле, а через предыдущий член.
А насчет `1/6` и `1.0/6.0` - перестраховка от привидения вычисления к виду `int(1)/int(6)=0`

Answer (score 0):

Есть подозрение, что если переменной double присвоить 1/6,
и если другой переменной double присвоить 1.0/6.0 - то результат (значение этих переменных) будет не идентичен ! (зависит от компилятора), т.к. значение 1/6 может быть вычислено как int т.е. целое число, т.е. 0, а значение 1.0/6.0 явно указывает что это не целые числа, а double, и значение будет близко к правде.

То, почему делят на 6 а не на пять - зависит от логики решения задачи. Это не вопрос программирования.

Comment: То есть можно не заморачиватся по поводу 1/6,  почему именно 1/6 присваивается и S и T, вот этот момент меня напряг, ни как не могу понять, так как это не вопрос программирования?

Comment: Тип деления (вещественное или целочисленное) зависит от типа аргументов, а не от компилятора.

Answer (score -1):

Наивно кажется, что `s = 1/6` и `t = 1/6` это просто, просто стремление зависать дробь 1/6 c увеличенной точностью.

Может так вас будет смущать меньше:

```
double s,t;

s = 1/6;
t = 1/6;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вот тут меня и интересует, от куда берется это, почему именно 1 нужно делить на 6, а не какие-то другие числа?

Comment: Вы знаете, тут по соседству считают, точно такой же ряд.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576536/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E

Мое подозрение почему присваивается значение суммы s = 1/6. Скорее всего потому они не хотят считать с первого члена ряда i = 1 . Но это только подозрение.
Программа, в прикрепленной ссылке, мне кажется более наглядно написанной.

Answer (score -1):

Если буквально, то эта строка кода означает присваивание переменным `e` и `t` занчение `1/6` (одна шестая). 
Т.о. в контексте остального кода, мы считаем сумму не вышеприведенного ряда. ИМы начинаем от одной шестой, а не от единицы.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить почему именно считаем с одной шестой, а не с единицы или вообще с двойки? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: По-моему, ответ прост: код не соответствует ряду. Для того, чтобы считать ряд, который вы привели выше, Вам надо просто заменить одну шестую на 1.

Comment: То есть, можно 1/6 заменить на 1, правильно ли я понимаю, это 1/6 выходит это как бы начальное значение с какого начнется подсчет ряда?

Comment: Вы верно поняли, однако, я ошибся. Прошу прощения, я поторопился с выводами. Надо ещё подумать, такое впечатления, что код неверный.
Счет ряда начинается с 1. Её определяет начальное значение переменной `i` в цикле `for`. А вот причем здесь 1/6 ? Непонятно... Логично предположить, что `s` должна быть равна `0`. Т.е. сумма ряда изначально должна быть 0. А вот с `t` вопрос остается.

Comment: Одна шестая это первый член ряда при `i=1`.

Comment: То есть код правильный, и 1/6 это идет как первый член, с математической стороны?

Comment: Как я и говорил ранее: код не соответствует ряду. Он вообще неверный.
Одна шестая это первый член ряда при `i=1`.
Первые 2 строки цикла неверны. При начальном `s=t=1/6`, начальное значение `i` должно быть равно `2`. А строка `t *= -i / (i + 3.0);` вообще похожа на попытку совместить смену знака члена ряда (ряд знакочередующийся из-за растущей степени -1 в числителе) с вычислением знаменателя. В общем, вычисление члена ряда ошибочно. Даже если запись ряда изменить, чтобы знаменатель соответсвовал коду. Знак `*=` это вычисление геометричекой прогрессии, но никак не суммирование ряда.

Comment: Правильный (я не компилил) код для этого ряда появился в вопросе - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576536/221617

Comment: `присваивание переменным e ... значение 1/6` – переменная `e` инициализируется не константой 1/6, а пользовательским вводом из консоли.

Comment: @Arhad, я исправился в [коментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576897/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/576904?noredirect=1#comment763135_576904).

Comment: Заибраю свои слова назад, сказанные в [комментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576897/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/576904?noredirect=1#comment763232_576904)

[Ответ автора кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576939/221617) всё объясняет. Код лаконичный, но решение неочевидное, имхо.

[Я решил так](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576977/221617)